# Can i combine do loop with if

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I want to copy 5x25 cells from the F row. I have the idea to use the do loop to do the task until it copied 5x25 data to the other cell. The next thing is to check with the if statement if 4 or less cells don't have data in from the 5 selected cells than go to the next 5 cells and firstly check them and if they have 5 data copy them.

Here's my code maybe it can be understandable more.

```
Const START_ROW As Long = 17
Const NUM_ROWS As Long = 124

Dim FileToOpen As String
Dim objWb As Workbook, objWs As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long, DLast As Long
Dim i As Integer

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
                                        Title:="Válassza ki a fájlt!")

If FileToOpen = "False" Then Exit Sub 'if a file is not selected close the window and stop the macro

Set wsDest = ActiveSheet             'pasting here; or specify some other sheet... anyway its working only with the active sheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen, ReadOnly:=True)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("SMI_650_Lxy")       'or whatever sheet you need

wsDest.Cells.Locked = False

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
DLast = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
If LastRow < START_ROW Then LastRow = START_ROW

FirstRow = IIf(LastRow - NUM_ROWS >= START_ROW, LastRow - NUM_ROWS, START_ROW) 'find first row

Debug.Print "FirstRow" & vbTab & FirstRow 'test in the immediate windows
Debug.Print "LastRow" & vbTab & LastRow
Debug.Print "START_ROW" & vbTab & START_ROW

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("F" & FirstRow & ":F" & LastRow)) = 125 Then
ws.Range("A" & FirstRow & ":FF" & LastRow).Copy wsDest.Cells(START_ROW, "A")
Else
For i = 4 To 25
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("F" & LastRow - i & ":F" & LastRow - 4 - i)) = 5 Then
    ws.Range("F" & LastRow - i & ":F" & LastRow - 4 - i).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & DLast + i & ":FF" & DLast + 4 + i)
    Else
    End If
Next i
End If
```

Comment: Sounds like its time to find a VBA tutorial and spend a little while reading.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with your code?

Comment: In the last section with the if and for  statement I try to sort out in the range of 5 cells there's any empty cell. The problem is after a while the for loop stops and there's a chance to it will not copy 125 cells just less. That's why I thinked about that do-if combination because with the in I can sort and with the do I can check if it copied 125 cells.